# Behaviour of calling scheduleRepeating() on running DispatchSourceTimer?

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-queue

I have a running `DispatchSourceTimer` that is created with:

```
self.timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: .init(rawValue: 0), queue: self.myQueue)
self.timer!.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now(), interval: .milliseconds(100))
self.timer!.setEventHandler(handler: self.myHandler)
```

What happens when I call:

```
self.timer!.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now(), interval: .milliseconds(100))
```

at a later time? Does it reset the timer and make it start 'counting milliseconds' again?

The [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsourcetimer/2016060-schedulerepeating) explains nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

Yes, *it resets the timer and makes it start again*

---

You could test it yourself in a Playground ...